# Where can I buy raw manga in PDF format?

Tags: manga-production

I'd like to purchase the original Japanese manga in digital form but prefer in PDF format as I don't want to be tied down to using a particular website or even losing my purchased manga (I remember buying a digital manga a couple years ago but when I logged into my account recently it was no longer there.)

Comment: I do not think you can purchase manga in PDF format. The whole point of tying your purchased manga to your website account is to avoid redistribution. If you really want to save the manga to your own device, the only way is to save all the pages as images as you read them on the website. But even this is only supported by few digital manga sellers.

Comment: You could buy them as epub and convert them to pdf

Comment: How about this website? https://www.comixology.com/Manga

Comment: @GermaVinsmoke that might be an answer... but looks like Comixology only provides translated manga instead of Japanese raw, and also [there's no (popular) manga on DRM-free shops](https://www.comixology.com/DRM-Free-Comics/page/2794?tid=W140717001&utm_source=cmx_hompage&utm_medium=DRM_Free&utm_campaign=W140710001_DRM_Free)?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there are *no* raw, digital manga being sold in PDF format. You can convert them, however, using applications found in the Internet. Here are some sites I found that sell raw, digital manga (and there are more mentioned in the forum links I posted below):

1. https://booklive.jp
2. https://www.ebookjapan.jp/ebj/
3. https://www.cmoa.jp
4. https://books.rakuten.co.jp/e-book/
5. https://sokuyomi.jp
6. https://bookwalker.jp
7. https://honto.jp
8. https://www.amazon.co.jp

Where I found those sites above:

1. https://www.reddit.com/r/manga/comments/3ekjyj/sites_to_buy_raw_manga_from/
2. https://www.reddit.com/r/LearnJapanese/comments/212get/is_there_a_way_to_buy_legal_digital_copies_of/
3. https://www.reddit.com/r/manga/comments/7hg7i6/best_legal_japanese_ebook_sites_for_raw_manga/

Answer (score 0):

**Japanese DLsite** provides few Japanese manga in DRM-free PDF formats. The files can be downloaded and opened freely without any additional restriction.

The following search is for ["Safe-For-Work" (as per their definition) manga](https://www.dlsite.com/home/fsr/=/language/jp/ana_flg/off/age_category%5B0%5D/general/work_category%5B0%5D/books/genre_and_or/or/options_and_or/or/exclude_protect/1/file_type%5B0%5D/PDF/file_type_name%5B0%5D/PDF/per_page/30/show_type/3/without_order/1/page/1/order/price_d); this excludes doujinshi and R-18 works but includes tankobon (単行本), magazine/anthology (雑誌/アンソロ), short story (短編), per-chapter (単話), and free-reading trial/demo (無料お試し版).